# Difference between R CMD build and R CMD INSTALL --build in R

Tags: r, build, installation

I wanted to know what is the difference between R CMD build and R CMD INSTALL --build in R, from results point of view?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds a lot like [this question](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-January/063511.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R CMD build builds a source package tarball, that can be distributed, installed or checked.

R CMD INSTALL --build makes a binary package, that can be installed without any compilation, i.e. that contains no sources.